# URL Rewriting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I just can’t figure out why RewritePath method is not working in this code.
When I try to browse the Project from ProductPage.aspx page, the URL in address bar is still shown as http://localhost:44789/ProductPage.aspx instead of being like this: 
http://localhost:44789/ProductPage.aspx/?color="

here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for GetProductInfo
/// </summary>
public class GetProductInfo:IHttpModule
{
    public GetProductInfo()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;

    }

    private void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication App = sender as HttpApplication;

        if (App.Request.Path.Contains("ProductPage.aspx"))
        {

            string[] Parts = App.Request.Path.Split('/');
            App.Response.Write(Parts.Length);
            if (Parts.Length < 3)
                App.Context.RewritePath("ProductPage.aspx/?Color=");
            else
                App.Context.RewritePath("ProductPage.aspx?color=" + Parts[Parts.Length - 1]);

        }
    }
}
```

update: 
I`m still trying to solve this problem. i tried to run this code on other machines with  different OS still no luck.

Comment: have you stepped into the code at all and debugged it?  Is it hitting your rewrite code correctly?  Is it stepping through it?

Comment: yes i did. actually i see something here which i don`t know how to deal with it :

when i check app.context i saw this: App.Context.IsWebSocketRequest 'App.Context.IsWebSocketRequest' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

can you help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It won't change the URL in the address bar of the browser. It is an internal redirect.

For the long answer read http://www.dotnetperls.com/rewritepath and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath(v=vs.110).aspx.

You should look into the IIS URL Rewrite module http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite. That can do what you describe in your question.

Comment: thank you very much. that was the problem then, misunderstanding the true function of this method.